# How to make an animation of a curve from scratch using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

Note this is a follow-up question of [How to make an animation of a Lissajous curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686108/how-to-make-an-animation-of-a-lissajous-curve);

My first idea was to edit my original question and ask for the animation, but I understand and respect SO way of operating. So the best is making another question.

I want to make an animation of the curve (where you incrementally draw it) with parametrization: x(t) = sin(3t) and y(y) = sin(4t) where t[0, 2pi].

For doing so I would add the code:

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'b')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    x.append(np.sin(4*frame))
    y.append(np.sin(3*frame))
    ln.set_data(x, y)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
```

The problem is that with this code it doesn't draw the whole curve from scratch. What does is overdrawing it, getting overlapping.

How can I draw it from scratch (i.e. starting with white background)? I've been thinking about an if else but got nothing.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Let me show you the whole code:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# set the minimum potential
rm = math.pow(2, 1 / 6)
t = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000, endpoint = False)
x = []
y = []

for i in t: #TypeError 'int' object is not iterable
    x_i = np.sin( 3 * i )
    y_i = np.sin( 4 * i )
    x.append(x_i)
    y.append(y_i)

# set the title
plt.title('Plot sin(4t) Vs sin(3t)')

# set the labels of the graph
plt.xlabel('sin(3t)')
plt.ylabel('sin(4t)')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'b')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    x.append(np.sin(4*frame))
    y.append(np.sin(3*frame))
    ln.set_data(x, y)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)

# display the graph
plt.show()
```

This is the image I get at the beginning (screenshot taken after approximately 1s after started running; that's why you see that funny line): https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwC6D.jpg. As you can see it doesn't start from scratch (i.e not from white background)

This is the plot I get at the end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMmbf.jpg

I am seeking getting that ending point but drawing everything from scratch, without starting with the shown plot.

Comment: Your code runs fine and produces the animation from scratch if you actually define `x` and `y`, e.g. `x=[]; y=[]`, before appending anything to them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for your comment. I have added the whole code and more details. I am still getting the graph from a based plot (please see first image). Thank you for your help

Comment: There is a for loop in your code which fills the arrays with values before you start the animation. My suggestion from my first comment stays valid: Start with empty `x` and `y` lists.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see. I removed it and now it starts from scratch. But I think I get a slightly different curve now. Should I add the for loop again but in a different part of the whole code (sorry for these really basic Qs btw).

Comment: You can use `frames=t` to get the same curve.

Comment: I run the same code using frames=t instead of frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128) but got the same different curve: https://imgur.com/a/tRLamTg

Comment: You also need to become clear about whether you want to show *x=sin(4w), y=sin(3w)* or *x=sin(3w), y=sin(4w)*.

Comment: What I miss, my bad... now it is clear, thank you so much!