# How to plot the normal at a point for a given parametric curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

**I want to draw the normal of a curve at a specific point** t_0 = 2*sp.pi/5.

The curve is given by the parametric equations x(t) = sin(3t) and y(y) = sin(4t) where t[0, 2pi]. For this type of parametric curve, the parameter equations for the normal line are given by the following equations:

[image]

Attempt:

```
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

t,t_0 = sp.symbols('t t_0',real=True)
r_x = sp.sin(3*t)
diff_r_x = sp.diff(r_x, t)
r_y = sp.sin(4*t)#typo has been edited
diff_r_y = sp.diff(r_y, t)

para_eqx = r_x.subs(t, t_0) + diff_r_x.subs(t, t_0)*(t-t_0)#paremeter eq. of the normal defined
para_eqy = r_y.subs(t, t_0) - diff_r_x.subs(t, t_0)*(t-t_0)#paremeter eq. of the normal defined

r_x_normal = para_eqx.subs(t_0, 2*sp.pi/5)#plugging in t_0 = 2*sp.pi/5
r_y_normal = para_eqy.subs(t_0, 2*sp.pi/5)#plugging in t_0 = 2*sp.pi/5

t_range_normal = np.linspace(0, 250, 100) #from here on I have no clear idea on what is wrong.

xmarks = sp.lambdify(t, r_x_normal, "numpy")(t_range_normal)
ymarks = sp.lambdify(t, r_y_normal, "numpy")(t_range_normal)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
complete_curve = ax.plot(xmarks, ymarks, ":", color="grey", alpha=0.5)
piece_of_curve = ax.plot(xmarks[:51], ymarks[:51], color="blue")
ax.plot(xmarks[50], ymarks[50], "o", color="blue")

plt.show()
```

I am struggling to evaluate these equations for values of t (given by t_range_normal). I used lambdify, and then plot the normal on the figure using a blue line.

However, I get:

[image]

Which is incorrect. I must be missing something from t_range_normal = np.linspace(0, 250, 100) on...

Thank you.

Comment: in your question you say `y(y) = sin(4t)` and `t_0 = 2\pi/5`. You probably mean: `y(t) = cos(3t) ` and `t_0 = 2*pi/5` as in your code?

Comment: @Gio you are right, there are typos. The question is right and the code wrong. Let me edit it. I keep getting the same plot (which indeed is a bad sign).

Comment: How should the plot look like?

Comment: @Gio I do not know, but it cannot be just a half diagonal. What I know is how the plot of the parametric equations x(t) = sin(3t) and y(y) = sin(4t) looks like: please see the answer to this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686108/how-to-make-an-animation-of-a-lissajous-curve

Comment: If your equations are correct, the one in the picture in your question and x(t) and y(t) are defined as in your question then you will always get a diagonal

Comment: Check the answer, it was too long to write it as a comment and it explains what is going on

Comment: If the math is correct, the code is now correct (once the typos have been fixed) and the problem is not with the code anymore. You should post on mathstackexchange. We can't help you solve a problem that is not there =)

Comment: @Gio Then the plot is correct... Yes I will post on MSE to completely understand why we get the diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is your code, let's go through it step by step:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t,t_0 = sp.symbols('t t_0',real=True)
r_x = sp.sin(3*t)
diff_r_x = sp.diff(r_x, t)
r_y = sp.sin(4*t)
diff_r_y = sp.diff(r_y, t)
```

```
r_x_eq= r_x.subs(t, t_0)
r_y_eq = r_y.subs(t, t_0)

r_x_eq
Out: sin(3*t_0)
r_y_eq
Out: sin(4*t_0)

r_x_eq.subs(t_0, 2*sp.pi/5)
Out: -sqrt(-sqrt(5)/8 + 5/8)
r_y_eq.subs(t_0, 2*sp.pi/5)
Out: -sqrt(-sqrt(5)/8 + 5/8)
```

Which is correct as you are doing a full round around the unit circle and sin(0) = sin(360) = sin(720) etc. etc.

The second term of your parametric function is the same (but with opposed sign) for x and y (according to the figure you posted in your question):

```
para_eqx = r_x.subs(t, t_0) + diff_r_x.subs(t, t_0)*(t-t_0)#paremeter eq. for the normal defined
para_eqy = r_y.subs(t, t_0) - diff_r_x.subs(t, t_0)*(t-t_0)#paremeter eq. for the normal defined
```

Hence your two functions are:

```
r_x_normal = para_eqx.subs(t_0, 2*sp.pi/5)#plugging in t_0 = 2*sp.pi/5
r_x_normal
Out[:]: 3*(-sqrt(5)/4 - 1/4)*(t - 2*pi/5) - sqrt(-sqrt(5)/8 + 5/8)

r_y_normal = para_eqy.subs(t_0, 2*sp.pi/5)#plugging in t_0 = 2*sp.pi/5
r_y_normal
Out[:]: -3*(-sqrt(5)/4 - 1/4)*(t - 2*pi/5) - sqrt(sqrt(5)/8 + 5/8)
```

Hence, for each given `t` they will differ only by a constant term.

```
t_range_normal = np.linspace(0, 250, 100) #from here on I have no clear idea on what is wrong.

xmarks = sp.lambdify(t, r_x_normal, "numpy")(t_range_normal)
ymarks = sp.lambdify(t, r_y_normal, "numpy")(t_range_normal)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
complete_curve = ax.plot(xmarks, ymarks, ":", color="grey", alpha=0.5)
piece_of_curve = ax.plot(xmarks[:51], ymarks[:51], color="blue")
ax.plot(xmarks[50], ymarks[50], "o", color="blue")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does 'Out' do? I see it helps to visualize what a variable contains. I am asking because I have never used it.

Comment: @Scientist is not a function. I was just marking the output returned by the previous line. For example `In: r_y_normal
Out: -3*(-sqrt(5)/4 - 1/4)*(t - 2*pi/5) - sqrt(sqrt(5)/8 + 5/8)`